# How to track anonymous events in Mixpanel

Tags: ruby, mixpanel

mixpanel's documentation says that

```
tracker.track(user_id, 'Sent Message')
```

which requires a user_id to be the source of the event.

What do I do if the user isn't logged it or the event just happens without the user interaction? for example, a redirect caused by some dynamic data

is there a way to track event (with the ruby api) that isn't matched to a user?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to track an event without a distinct_id (aka user_id) at the API level, but it's not a good idea because this event will not be usable in any report except "Segmentation" with the "Total" parameter (i.e. it will be useless in Segmentation+Unique, Retention, and Funnel reports). At that point, it's likely better to just not send anything, since it can never be attributed to a user.

If you're really just looking for counts of an event, you can simply generate a UUID. Don't default to -1, null, or another catchall as this can have unintended consequences.